# Google API: Understanding redirect URI

Tags: python, google-analytics

I want to use Google API to track the number of tweets a particular website  (say Rbloggers) make each day. And I am trying to do it in Python.

I am completely new to this. So, I was looking at the `hello-analytics-api`, in which I need to deal with `OAuth 2.0`. And I have no idea what to put down for the `redirect URI`.

I have read 
[What's a redirect URI? how does it apply to iOS app for OAuth2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281084/whats-a-redirect-uri-how-does-it-apply-to-ios-app-for-oauth2-0)

But I still don't quite understand the concepts and what I should put down for the 'redirect URI' ?

Answer (score 1):

From [Choosing a redirect URI](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#choosingredirecturi)

> When you create a client ID in the Google Developers Console, two redirect_uris are created for you: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob and `http://localhost`. The value your application uses determines how the authorization code is returned to your application.

In case of desktop apps or programs, you should set it to `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` so that you will be redirected to the page where you can copy the authorization code from internet browser and paste it in your desktop app

Comment: How can I get this link then ?

Comment: Could you specify how you mean to access the API?

Comment: To be honest, my task is to: use Google Analytics data to track the number of tweets R bloggers make per day as well as the incoming traffic from twitter. I was given a hint to look at the Google API documentation for info on what data can be scraped using Google Analytics:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#q_summary
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=visitor
This is what i am asked to do ultimately. I was so confused. I do not have a clue what approach and how to do this.