# Discord won't allow me to select the type of uri or generate URL

Tags: discord, permissions, bots

I have created a discord bot and I'm configuring the permissions so that I can generate an invite link.

When I selected the bot option it would not give me any options to choose my redirect url and would not allow me to enter anything into my redirect URI filed even when I have administrator privileges set

and given the bot all the available scopes including the bot option.

As you can see there is no drop down option to select from in the **Select Redirect URL**

[image]

I have given my bot all the available scopes as well as access to all the privileged intents. I have also given it administrator permissions.

It's permission's integer is 8 and I have made sure that it is a public bot.

I have also tried out different combinations of scopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a little bit of experimentation and it seems that you need to set your redirect URIs in the 'General' tab of the OAuth2 section, like this:

[image]

It will then appear as an option in the URL Generator tab like this:

[image]

I hope this solves your issue!

Comment: Hey man thanks so much for replying. So basically I need a URL to construct my URI do you know if just any URL will work because I'm looking to use this bot in production I'm not sure if the development server localhost:3000 will work? Why not just add in a redirect URL to discord.com/myserver? Since redirects are only there to display a confirmation message and a few other things right?

Comment: As far as I understand (and I am not an expert on OAuth2), the redirect URI just tells the browser where to 'send' the user to after they have successfully authenticated themselves using the link they were given. In this case, the URL that is being generated here is the OAuth2 authentication link providing the scopes you have selected. So I suppose you would want to send the user back to the application they are being authenticated to use. Obviously this could be anywhere, so Discord allows you to specify exactly where you want to direct them.

Comment: Here's a handy [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281084/whats-a-redirect-uri-how-does-it-apply-to-ios-app-for-oauth2-0) that discusses a bit about redirect URIs, albeit in a slightly different context. It still applies to your case in the same way.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed to do. It's so clear now!

Comment: Glad to hear I could help! Happy Developing!